# Global error handling in marionette.js

Tags: backbone.js, error-handling, modal-dialog, marionette, server-error

The UI should have a global error handler that shows a popup message whenever an error is received through the API. I'm trying but I'm not getting, I did not find any example too. This should be done `Marionette.js`. Please help

I got a json file:

```
{
"errorcodes": [{
"message": "Invalid Email/Password Combination",
"reason": "com.catt.exceptions.catttCustomerPreferencesException: Invalid Email/Password Combination\r\n\tat com.catt.v1.controller.CustomersController.customerLogin(CustomersController.java:303)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1008.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerM...",
"type": "tCustomerPreferencesError"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) to listen for any error happening in $.ajax.

From there, you can make make a Marionnette Application (for example), handle the error, and display an alert

```
var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.vent.on('error', function(event, jqxhr){
    alert(jqxhr.responseText); 
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError){
    App.vent.trigger('error', event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError);    
});
```

Fiddle Here : http://jsfiddle.net/8ff4n9ut/

Comment: Thanks! still i'm not able to do!Please look over the above reply!

Comment: Can you describe your issue or post some code in your question ?

Comment: I don't have the code,the general idea is that if a JSON response has the "errors" attribute, the message(s) shown within the errors array should be displayed to the user via a popup.

Comment: I edited my answer, the server response is given by ```jqxhr.responseText```

Comment: It will be triggered by any requests that return a status code in the 4xx (401, 403, 404, ...) and 5xx range. If your server returns a proper status code for a Sign in error (401), then yes, it will be triggered

Comment: Whenever an error is received, any other listeners to that ajax request's "done" method should not be called, how to do it please explain!